# "Legacy Driver Implementation Documentation for mongodb" - is there the new one?

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on a mongodb driver in a program. language in which it's not implemented yet. [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/) the documentation says

```
struct MsgHeader {
    int32   messageLength; // total message size, including this
    int32   requestID;     // identifier for this message
    int32   responseTo;    // requestID from the original request
                           //   (used in reponses from db)
    int32   opCode;        // request type - see table below
}
```

I wonder, why the category where it's located is titled "**Legacy** Driver Implementation Documentation". Is it really legacy? Is there the Driver Implementation Documentation"?

Comment: Which language? The majority of drivers generally base from the C implemenation or at least the BSON part, with optional "fallback" cases where a compiler is not available in the environment they are built in.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, how does that matter which language? Explain. I'm asking about the documentation.

Comment: Well the documentation itself references a C struct, so that should be an indication. How does it matter? Not re-inventing the wheel for one. And if you are talking about implementing a driver yourself for language "xyz" but don't tell anyone what language that is, then you are not likely to get much help are you? Perhaps consider the "commentary" here to be experienced pointers, rather than just idle chatter. The recomendation here was *"Give us more information"* to clear up the question you are actually asking.StackOverflow is a Question and Anwer resource. For dicussion, ask elsewhere.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, how does that matter in which language it is?

Comment: @BlakesSeven, - **so that should be an indication.** - of what? You know of 2 different links for language A and language B?